# In WSO2 ESB i want convert my date object to specific time zone

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, wso2, wso2-esb

Following Function is not supported in WSO2 ESB script datamapper Javascript function.

```
new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York' })
```

Following is what i have used not supported. It gives the server current timezone reguardless of the time zone what i have given.

Is there any possibility to import a moment.js resource to javascript custom function in WSO2 datamapper.

Comment: This is off–topic here, but have a look at [*9 Javascript Time and Date Manipulation Libraries for 2018*](https://blog.bitsrc.io/9-javascript-date-time-libraries-for-2018-12d82f37872d). If you want a specific timezone, you might be able to program it yourself in less than 10 lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside wso2esb datamapper custom function you cannot use toLocaleString to change the time zones of you date objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using -

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ctoc_timezone

The conversion is very simple.

Changing format and TimeZone:

`CtoC.toTimeZone(new Date(),"EST","Do MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss #{EST}");`

Output :

`28th Feb 2013 19:00:00 EST`